# Cypress waitUntill retiers after 400ms, how to prolong its timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, cypress, wait

I am working on a progress bar.

I click on a button that initiates the progress bar
Then I used waitUntill to wait till the progress bar (cyElement) is not visible
I verify that a second control (cyElement2) is now visible

```
cy.waitUntil(()=> {
            cy.get(cyElement).should('not.be.visible')
              
        }).then(()=>{ cy.get(cyElement2).should('be.visible') });
```

The below code waits only 400ms to check if the progress bar (cyElement) is not visible. How do I make it wait longer ?
Adding timeout=40000 will destroy the purpose of waitUntill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cy.waitUntil(()=> {
            cy.get(cyElement, {timeout:180000}).should('not.be.visible')
              
        }).then(()=>{ cy.get(cyElement2).should('be.visible') });
```

So it happens that if we add timeout in get command, the subsequent commands to this get will also get the same timeout.

And if I add a timeout of 10 minutes but the assertions get passed in 3 minutes then cypress will move over to the next command. So adding timeout does not mean hardcoding wait it is similar to explicit wait in selenium

Refer :
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Applying-Timeouts

Comment: I wonder if [cy.tick()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/tick) might be used instead of `cy.waitUntil()` and a long timeout?